# squid proxy multiple ip

Tags: linux, ubuntu, squid

i got a ubuntu vps and i want to turn it to a proxy server with multiple ip,so far every guid just needs me to a range of ip for this proxy like 49.12.xxx.101 but i got only one ip for this vps

```
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:3128 name=3128
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8000 name=8000
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8585 name=8080

acl tasty3128 myportname 3128 src 49.12.xxx.101/24
http_access allow tasty3128
tcp_outgoing_address 49.12.xxx.101 tasty3128

acl tasty8000 myportname 8000 src 49.12.xxx.101/24
http_access allow tasty3129
tcp_outgoing_address 49.12.xxx.102 tasty8000

acl tasty8080 myportname 8080 src 49.12.xxx.101/24
http_access allow tasty3130
tcp_outgoing_address 49.12.xxx.103 tasty8080
```

i tried this config but this is not working as well. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the additional IP addresses from your hosting provider and configure them in your operating system.

Comment: but Hetzner only gives 3 additional ip , so is the max proxy ip i can get is only 4?

Comment: what are you trying to solve with these ips?

Comment: IPv4 addresses are really hard to get, that is why operators don't want to give too many of them for customer use.

Comment: @djdomi im trying to use them for a bot thatvisits a website. i was able to use ipv6 but website blocks the bots cuase of too many request from 1 ip! is there any way to get difrent ip?

Comment: Working around restrictions of web site owners is not showing good business practices, therefore this question is off-topic for ServerFault.com.

Comment: Agreed, we not provide support for f* soneones website